# How to update a label text with button inside a collection view in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4

I have a collection view inside a table view. There are two plus minus buttons in collection view cell. Now i have to update a label on the plus minus buttons action which is outside of table view. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I have to update a Slot: (label) by clicking on plus minus button.

I tried something like this with the delegate protocol.

I declare a delegate in my collection view class.

```
 protocol SlotsCollectionViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
func didTapOnIncrement(Int: Int)
func didTapOnDecrement(Int: Int)
```

}

//after that,

```
 var delegate: SlotsCollectionViewCellDelegate?


 @IBAction func plusBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
     self.delegate?.didTapOnIncrement(Int: cartCount)
  }

   @IBAction func minusBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
     delegate?.didTapOnDecrement(cell: self)
   }
```

And in my Main View Controller

```
extension MainViewController: SlotsCollectionViewCellDelegate {

func didTapOnIncrement(Int: Int) {
       cartSlot_lbl.text = Int.description
     }

     func didTapOnDecrement(Int: Int) {
         cartSlot_lbl.text = Int.description
     }
```

}

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I tried with a delegate method but that's not working for me.

Comment: can you add the code you have for the button

Comment: ' @IBAction func plusBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {

         if Counter <= avail_Slot! - count_Slot {
             
          Counter += count_Slot
             
         }
         
         digit_Lbl.text = String(Counter)
         
         
         cartCount += cartCountSlot!
         print(cartCount)
         

        
        VC.cartSlot_lbl.text = cartCount.description
         
         
     }

Comment: cartSlot is a label where I have to show the cartCount.

Comment: @Joby is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, each time you push + or - you want to update slot label. In my opinion the easiest and fastest way to achieve this it's using **NotificationCenter.default.post**

In your collection view cell on button action write:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("postAction"), object: numberToIncreaseOrDecrease)
```

In your MainViewController where you have the slot label, add this code in view did load:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateSlotValue(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("postAction"), object: nil)
```

And out from the view did load add this function:

```
 @objc func updateSlotValue(_ notification: Notification) {
    let value = notification.object as! Int
    cartSlot_lbl.text.text = value
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) In my opinion it's the easiest and fastest way for observe in real time changes from a collection view or table view cell.

Comment: @saumyaranjanGangwar sending notifications is just what I suggested you in my answer below, actually even more detailed. I don't understand why this is more correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think delegates are the right choice for that. If it didn't work, please explain why and show some code, you probably forgot to set a delegate reference.

Anyway, here's some more thoughts:

- You could use a Reactive Pattern, so that you create a Relay to store your current values, manipulate them by providing input (times etc.) and subscribe to them from the Class where the "Spot:" Label is implemented. Whenever your model changes, your  Spot Label will also be changed.
- You could also implement something using Notifications. Basically speaking, the difference to using a reactive pattern is not that big, you simply have to care about the "notify" part yourself. Assuming you have something like a Singleton Pattern applied where you store your entire State (selected dates/times, slots etc.), you could do that like this:

```swift
extension Notification.Name {
    static let modelDidChange = Notification.Name("modelDidChange")
}
// where your model lies
struct YourModel {
    var slots: Int = 0

    static var singletonInstance: YourModel = YourModel() {
        // use the didSet block to react to changes made to the model
        didSet {
            // send a notification so all subscriber know something has changed
            NotificationCenter.default.post(.modelDidChange)
        }
    }
}

class YourViewControllerWhereTheLabelIs: UIViewController {
    // ...
    var slotLabel: UILabel?

    // ...
    init() {
        // wherever you initialize your viewcontroller,
        // you could also do it in viewWillAppear
        // subscribe to the notification to react to changes
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modelDidChange), name: .modelDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        // just don't forget to unsubscribe
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func modelDidChange() {
        // update your label here, this is called whenever YourModel.singletonInstance is changed
        self.slotLabel?.text = YourModel.singletonInstance.slots
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you or gives you an idea. If I can be of more help just let me know.

Comment: Hi mmika, actually I define a delegate in collection view class and I am not able to set it in main ViewController class where is my slot label.

Comment: getting this error- "Cannot assign value of type 'MainViewController' to type 'CollectionViewCellDelegate?.Type'"

Comment: @saumyaranjanGangwar that means `MainViewController` does not conform to `CollectionViewCellDelegate` protocol. Go to your `MainViewController`, at the very bottom append 
`extension MainViewController: CollectionViewCellDelegate  { 
... 
// the required functions from CollectionViewCellDelegate 
// ... 
}`
with all the required functions implemented there and then it should work.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same thing but not getting output.

Comment: What about your "Cannot assign value of type 'MainViewController' to type 'CollectionViewCellDelegate?.Type'" Error then? Did you fix that? Did you assign the delegate property? And do you even call the delegate functions?